# How to parameterize a Maven file (pom.xml)?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a spring boot application where I want to package it according to the profile I am building with, for example when I issue profile `x`, I want maven to build as a `jar`; but when building with profile `y`, I want maven to build as a `war`.

I want something like:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <package>${buildMethod}</package>
</project>
```

Where `${buildMethod}` is the type of packaging.

This would be decided by executing a command i.e. `mvn package -P buildProfile`.

Comment: So, you want to  parameterize a Maven file?

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks for the proper question.

Comment: I threw in an example and clarified.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thanks a lot looks much better now ...

Comment: you shouldn't do that though, you should have a multi-module maven project and have a module per each packacing type. What you want is a trick which can lead to maintenance headaches in the future

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this would help:

```
<profiles>   
  <profile>
      <id>war</id>
      <properties>
          <deploy.type>war</deploy.type>
      </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
      <id>jar</id>
      <properties>
          <deploy.type>jar</deploy.type>
      </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

And then just use this property placeholder `${deploy.type}`.

Comment: It is so easy that I am ashamed to post the question ... :(

Comment: Don't forget to mention `mvn package -P war` corresponds to the `id` for the `war` profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add profiles, with a list of properties, to your pom file.

Build using:

- `mvn package` - Builds a WAR by default (implicit)
- `mvn package -P deployWar` - Builds a WAR
- `mvn package -P deployJar` - Builds a JAR

```html
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>

  <package>${deployment.type}</package>

  <profiles>

    <!-- This profile deploys the application as a WAR (default) -->
    <profile>
      <id>deployWar</id>
      <properties>
        <deployment.type>war</deployment.type>
      </properties>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
    </profile>

    <!-- This profile deploys the application as a JAR -->
    <profile>
      <id>deployJar</id>
      <properties>
        <deployment.type>jar</deployment.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
</project>
```